# DB2 read bulk data

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I am reading bulk data from database with a size of 100mb.
What I am doing is reading it in a procedure and building a xml which is amazingly very fast.
So I am calling the stored procedure via Hibernate through JDBC in which the transmission takes too long, because of the large xml.
I am thinking of to zip the file in the procedure.
Does DB2 LUW supporting zipping from a stored procedure?

Comment: You will need to compress the result-set column yourself (and application layer de-compress).  Sanity check that design, it seems a poor design to have 100megabyte chunks transiting between client and server, unless as a one off.

Comment: What do you mean with "result-set column yourself (and application layer de-compress)"?
I am thinking of to split the calls by using paging and on the application side to collect and build the whole xml.

Comment: Unless I completely misunderstand you, the file you mention is just the result set from your query? You can write a function in any of the existing languages (java, python, ...) that transforms your xml into a blob with compressed content. But for 100Mb (unless you have a superslow connection) I doubt that compress/transfer/uncompress will outperform transfer in a significant way. Have you concidered using JSON/BSON over XML?

Comment: Yes it is the result set from the query which I now change it to JSON format, which is definitely smaller.  My application function calls a stored procedure which generates a CLOB (with JSON content). I split the call in several calls read  only in 10MB pieces. But what I want is to retrieve the data in compressed mode. When I zip the 10 MB on application side, than it will be less than 1MB.